# Bash - to pass to rm a filename which is in a variable, but with ! option

Tags: bash, rm

the command

```
rm  !("$filename")
```

does not work, because it is syntactically incorrect.

I want to remove other files in a directory but that one specified in the $filename variable.

Actually, the bash script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$(ls -t | grep radar_ | head -n 1)"
echo "${filename}"
rm  !("$filename")
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It may be necessary to turn on extglob. See `shopt extglob` and `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Adding `shopt -s extglob`    helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
DIR="/path_to_your_dir"
for file in "${DIR}"/*; do 
  [[ $file = "${filename}" ]] || rm "${file}"
done
```

Or something like :

```
DIR="/path_to_your_dir"
ls -1 "${DIR}"|grep -v "${filename}"|xargs -I{} rm {}
```

Or something like :

```
 find "${DIR}" ! -name "${filename}" -exec rm {} \;
 find "${DIR}" ! -name "${filename}" -a -type f -exec rm {} \; # apply the rm only on files (not on the directories for example)
```

Personally I'd choose the `find` solution to do that kind of tasks (searching and doing operation on some files).

Comment: The `find "${DIR}" ! -name "${filename}" -type f -exec rm {} \;` removes everything from the directory and not keep the file specified in the $filename variable. What am I missing here?

Comment: @PalCsanyi try to remove `-type f` or add a `-a` between the two conditions.

Comment: @Idriss Neumann Thank you very much. The `-a` solved my problem.

Comment: Using `ls` shouldn't even be considered; you should remove that example.

Comment: @chepner I'm not so categorical as you about that. I mean yes of course using `ls` inside a script is usually cause of bugs like the famous `for i in $(ls ...)` case, which is not working well when the filename contains blanks. But it's not the case with the way I use it. And the purpose of this version is to show how we can deal with `grep -v` and `xargs`. And I said that I prefer to use `find` to do that kind of tasks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `shopt -s extglob` helped.

So the bash script is now:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x

shopt -s extglob

filename="$(ls -t | grep radar_ | head -n 1)"
echo "${filename}"
rm  !("$filename")
```

Thanks Cyrus!

Comment: But the script remove any file except that specified in the $filename variable. So this is not the solution.